# IONIC - Cordova Globalization deprecated, how use navigator

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I get a warning that Globalization is deprecated and an Info-Link to https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/11/20/migrate-from-cordova-globalization-plugin.html.

But I don't understand how can I use this in Ionic, how can I import the navigator in Angular 5?